# Javascript Closure YDNJS

Tags: javascript, closures

```
 var fn;
 function foo() {  
 var a = 2;
     function baz() {
         console.log( a );
     }
     fn = baz; // assign baz to global variable
  }
 function bar() {
     fn(); // look ma, I saw closure!
  }
 foo();
 bar(); // 2
```

I have no idea with this code:
First, why the author have to wrap fn in a function that call fn(function bar), why don't call is simply outside the global scope like "fn();",I've tried it and result in the same
Second, is it a good way to assign a function to a variable?, I thought it could only copy the structure of the function and reconstruct in the variable(which means it have no reference or simply cannot remember the environment by foo) 
Third, The author said that engine remain all the closure whenever there is one who using what concern to that environment, but here, I just see that there's a assignment, so is it right if fn is using baz that leads to the remain of environment of foo to fn?(which make fn can use the variable "a")

Comment: He is explaining how scoping works with examples.

Comment: can you clear your idea, i don't really get it

Comment: Can you please link the source of the code, and what the author wrote about it?